# How to display different image with FileDialog?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to display image files with JS using createcomponent in a list model. I access the folder with FileDialog and the source property of my Image object is source: filedialog.fileUrl. I'm importing it to ListModel and UI using imagemodels.append() . My problem is: i am viewing the first photo 2nd and 3rd etc. I also view photos. So photos appear when FileDialog is triggered. But when I trigger it for the 3rd or 4th time, all 4 photos are the same, that is, it opens the fileUrl of the last photo. How can I get past this?

JS Functions

```
function addImage() {
    CreateObject.create("AddImage.qml", root, imageAdded);
}
function imageAdded (obj, source) {
    imagemodels.append({"obj": obj, "source": source})
}

function create(source, parent, callback) {
    _parent = parent;
    _callback = callback;
    _source = source;

    _component = Qt.createComponent(source);
    if (_component.status === Component.Ready || _component.status === Component.Error)
        createDone();
    else
        _component.statusChanged.connect(createDone);
}

function createDone()
{
    if (_component.status === Component.Ready)
    {
        var obj = _component.createObject(_parent);
        if (obj != null)
            _callback(obj, _source);
        else
            console.log("Error object: " + _source);

        _component.destroy();
    }
    else if (_component.status === Component.Error)
        console.log("Error component: " + component.errorString());
}
```

My AddImage file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import io.qt.examples.texteditor 1.0
import QtQuick 2.5

Image{
    width:80
    height:80
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    asynchronous: true
    source: filedialog.fileUrl
}
```

My FileDialog:

```
FileDialog {
    id: filedialog
    nameFilters: ["Image files (*.png *.jpg)"]
    onAccepted: { 
        addImage()
        console.log("Accepted Files:"+ fileUrls)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have! I think I know what you are doing wrong, but not sure without code

Comment: I added the codes @Amfasis

Answer (score 0):

You are actually binding the `source` property of the image to the `filedialog.fileUrl`, meaning that every time the `fileUrl` changes, that change will be reflected to all the binding (thus all the added images).

You should add the `fileUrl` as parameter to the `addImage` function.

However, it seems you are making stuff needlessly complicated. You are creating the object and when that is succeeded you add it to the ListModel. I propose to turn it around and let a `ListView` handle creation of the objects from the `ListModel`:

```
ListModel {
    id: imagemodels
}

ListView {
    model: imagemodels

    delegate: Image{
        width:80
        height:80
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        asynchronous: true
        source: model.source
    }
}

FileDialog {
    nameFilters: ["Image files (*.png *.jpg)"]
    onAccepted: imagemodels.append({"source": fileUrl})
}
```

I choose `ListView`, but you can also use `GridView`, `Repeater` or `TableView`. All readily implemented for you :-)